# Mosaic Dataset Footprint Field ordering

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, fields-attributes, mosaic-dataset, footprint

Is there any to order the Foot Print fields created in Raster Mosaic Dataset?

I know, we can edit, or reorder fields of any FeatureClass, or Shapefile using X-Ray ArcCatalog, ArcGIS Diagrammer.,

But I am looking for reordering fields of FootPrint creating in Mosaic Dataset. Like, I particularly want to add field of default field created during MosaicDataset..

Please refer the below figure. The Field "Positional Accuracy" have been added manually, which used be placed in the end of all fields. Raster(Field Order 1), and Name (Field Order2) Fields created automatically, while we create Raster Mosaic Dataset. I need to reorder the Positional Accuracy field (Field Order2), and Name field (Field Order 3)

[image]

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. When you open the attribute table of a layer in ArcMap you can change the order of the fields that are displayed, but this change is not permanent.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining my part correctly. Edits updated in the main question,.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in solution in ArcGIS to re-order fields of any feature class or shapefile. Since the Footprint feature class is a special feature of the Mosaic Dataset, there is even less chance of being able to modify the order of the fields.